# Error 403 trying to use CORS with a static website loading image hosted on AWS S3

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I have dumped a index.html file on my root folder (also on AWS S3 englify bucket) and am trying to load images onto the webpage from the images folder. My CORS configurations has been set to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>englify.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

and my request headers are as such:

```
Accept:image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8  
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br  
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6  
Cache-Control:max-age=0  
Connection:keep-alive  
Host:s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com  
If-Modified-Since:Wed, 26 Oct 2016 17:25:03 GMT  
If-None-Match:"f599a968271741f977379e125797434e"  
Referer:http://englify.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/  
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36
```

I understand that CORS looks for the "Origin" in the header but how do I set that for a html `<img>` tag? My only work around has been to make the image public.

Comment: Do you also get a 403 response if you type the image URL into your browser's address bar? (If so, this doesn't really to do with CORS, right? It's not a cross-origin technicality that's causing the 403 load; the resource is just *always* returning a 403 response.)

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you're mixing a few concepts here.

1. Web pages are free to embed static content (images, videos, etc) from other domains. The browser will typically happily let you.
2. For more dynamic stuff like AJAX calls, the browser by default protects you from doing calls to other domains. Reason is to protect you from malicious AJAX calls after being victim to a cross site scripting attack, for example. A CORS header on server B with allow-origin for server A, will instruct the browser rendering a site from server A to allow AJAX calls to server B.
3. S3 has access control on the files it serves to the internet.

In your case, you're embedding static images that are hosted on S3. S3 is responding with a 403. CORS protection happens on browser level. A 403 happens on HTTP level. So S3 is actually telling your browser that you're not allowed to fetch the images.
A way to check this: directly request the image from S3 in your browser. The same error should appear. That way, you can be sure that CORS issues are out of the question.

You've already found the solution to the problem: make the images public. Then S3 will happily serve then.

If you don't want to make the images public, you can look at the S3 docs how to protect them. But typically, the images will then only be available to users that have a session / are logged in to AWS. Another option would be to look at CloudFront, where you can define policies that allow you to generate a token in your web app that gives access to a specific CloudFront resource (which can be backed by S3).